# Can a player have more than one walk-up song at a time?

Tags: mlb

In the MLB, walk-up songs are played each time a batter walks up to the plate, or when a reliever gets the call from the bullpen.  The walk-up song itself is the same ~5-15 second portion of a song, and to my knowledge, does not change throughout a season for each player.

Has it ever happened, and is it even allowed, that a player can have multiple walk-up songs at one time, where the song played at any given time is random, like a jukebox?

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but an interesting article from 2013: [The secrets behind baseball's walk-up music](https://www.mercurynews.com/2013/06/10/the-secrets-behind-baseballs-walk-up-music-2/)